# What device does NetBSD use for a USB modem?

Tags: networking, usb, modem, netbsd

I'm testing some software on NetBSD 8.1 x86_64. The software opens a USB modem and issues AT commands. The software tested OK on Debian, Fedora, OS X, and OpenBSD. The software is having trouble on NetBSD.

NetBSD's `dmesg` shows:

```
umodem0 at uhub1 port 1 configuration 2 interface 0
umodem0: U.S.Robotics (0xbaf) USB Modem (0x303), rev 2.00/2.00, addr 2, iclass 2/2
umodem0: data interface 1, has CM over data, has break
umodem0: status change notification available
ucom0 at umodem0
```

If I am parsing the NetBSD man pages properly (which may not be the case), I should be able to access the modem via `/dev/ucom0`. Also see [`UMODEM(4)` man page](https://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?umodem+4.i386+NetBSD-8.1).

The test user is part of the `dialer` group. The software was not able to open `/dev/ucom0`, `/dev/umodem0`, `ucom0` or `umodem0`. All open's result in *`No such file or directory`*. Additionally, there are no `/dev/ttyACMn` or `/dev/cuaUn` devices.

How do I access the modem on NetBSD?

Comment: Silly comment, but does [any of this stuff on this page](https://www.netbsd.org/support/hardware/usb.html) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access the modem on NetBSD?

According to the NetBSD folks at [Trouble accessing USB modems on NetBSD 8.1 x86_64](https://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2019/11/25/msg023633.html):

- The USR modem was assigned `/dev/dtyU0`. After a reboot I was able to access the modem through the device.
- The Conexant modem with a CX93001 chip is a software modem. It uses a proprietary protocol from the chip to the driver. NetBSD does not have a driver for it, so it was assigned a `ugen0`. It can be accessed from `/dev/ugen0.00`, but it is not a tty device.

So to wrap this up for the BSDs, here are the devices to use to access a USB modem when things work as expected:

- DragonFly - `/dev/cuaU0`
- FreeBSD - `/dev/cuaU0`
- NetBSD - `/dev/dtyU0`
- OpenBSD - `/dev/cuaU0`
- OS X - `/dev/cu.usbmodem0000001`